# Which tense is it: "I've got a cat"?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

Which tense is it:

> I've got a cat.

I'm confused, is it *Present Perfect* or *Present Simple*?

Comment: Present tense. _I've_ means _I have_ and that's present tense. Some will tell you that it's present perfect tense, but that just means it's the perfect construction in the present tense. There isn't any "present simple" tense; there's only present and past, and they're both simple, so you don't need to say it. Everything else is constructions, not tenses.

Comment: Bear in mind, that I've got in BrE can mean I've gotten a cat in AmE. So....

Comment: More interestingly, it's arguable whether it's a present or perfect _construction_. Personally I'd lean towards present, but there are arguments for either interpretation.

Comment: @Janus: Maybe there flexibility in the *terminology*, but it's difficult to contrive a context for an alternative *meaning* with OP's present tense version. On the other hand, if we shift things back into the past, *I'd got a cat when I went to university* could easily mean that I *already* had a cat (which I took with me to uni, perhaps), OR that I acquired a cat as soon as I got there.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I don't think that arguing over semantic details is really the best way to help the OP.

Comment: @Lambie Do you mean that a British speaker might say "I've got a cat" with the meaning "I have obtained a cat", or that an American speaker might?

Comment: Yes, as in "I've got a lot of letter recently". AmE: I've gotten a lot of letters recently.

Answer (score 1):

Two present tenses in English for possession of an object with the verb have:
The following two sentences have exactly the same meaning in any variety of English: I've got a cat. [I "own" a cat]

I have a cat. [I "own" a cat]

The negatives and interrogatives of this are:

I haven't got a cat. I don't have a cat

Have you got a cat? Do  you have a cat?

There is one caveat here: In BrE: Have got **can also be** present perfect. So sentences like: Have you got many letters recently actually means: Have you received many letters recently. In AmE, this would be: Have you gotten many letters recently.

This can be a source of much confusion. Most native speakers of English are not even aware of this. They just "know it" (i.e. that Do you have  and Have you got mean the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

John Lawler answered in comments:

> Present tense. *I've* means *I have* and that's present tense. Some will tell you that it's present perfect tense, but that just means it's the perfect construction in the present tense. There isn't any "present simple" tense; there's only present and past, and they're both simple, so you don't need to say it. Everything else is constructions, not tenses.